# Orientdb Errors : can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler" etc

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm a total novice to graph database and I've giving Orientdb 2.2.34 a go.  I'm using a Windows 10 machine with Java 10.0.1 JRE and JDK.  When I run the server.bat file I get the following errors displayed and I don't know where to start to solve them:

> Can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: ..\log\orient-server.log.0.lck
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: ..\log\orient-server.log.0.lck
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.createLoggerHandlers(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1800(Unknown Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.accessCheckedHandlers(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getHandlers(Unknown Source)
>           at com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager.installCustomFormatter(OLogManager.java:84)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.(OServer.java:135)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.(OServer.java:118)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.create(OServerMain.java:28)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:47)
>
> 2018-05-01 21:47:35:110 INFO  Loading configuration from: C:/Program
>   Files/Orientdb-2.2.34/config/orientdb-server-config.xml...WARNING: An
>   illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal
>   reflective access by
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1
>   (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Orientdb-2.2.34/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3.jar) to
>   method
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 WARNING: Use
>   --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
>   denied in a future release
>
> 2018-05-01 21:47:35:371 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.34 (build
>   f340442755a31eabc91b87cb3ef99eda5cee6ebd, branch 2.2.x) is starting
>   up... 2018-05-01 21:47:35:377 INFO  Databases directory: C:\Program
>   Files\Orientdb-2.2.34\databases 2018-05-01 21:47:35:413 INFO 
>   Configuration of usage of soft references inside of containers of
>   results of SQL execution 2018-05-01 21:47:35:426 INFO  Initial and
>   maximum values of heap memory usage are equal, containers of results
>   of SQL executors will use soft references by default 2018-05-01
>   21:47:35:427 INFO  Auto configuration of disk cache size. 2018-05-01
>   21:47:35:483 INFO  8449830912 B/8058 MB/7 GB of physical memory were
>   detected on machine 2018-05-01 21:47:35:483 INFO  Detected memory
>   limit for current process is 8449830912 B/8058 MB/7 GB 2018-05-01
>   21:47:35:486 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=3,962MB
>   (heap=2,048MB direct=524,288MB os=8,058MB) 2018-05-01 21:47:35:599
>   INFO  {db=OSystem} Creating the system database 'OSystem' for current
>   serverException `1E7ECDE6` in storage `plocal:C:/Program
>   Files/Orientdb-2.2.34/databases/OSystem`: 2.2.34 (build
>   f340442755a31eabc91b87cb3ef99eda5cee6ebd, branch 2.2.x)
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot
>   create folders in storage with path C:/Program
>   Files/Orientdb-2.2.34/databases/OSystem
>           DB name="OSystem"
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.create(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:127)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:438)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:160)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1309)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate
>
> ```
> (OServer.java:367)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:48)
> Error during server execution
> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database 'OSystem'
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:506)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:160)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1309)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:367)
>         at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:48)
> Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot
> ```
>
> create folders in storage with path C:/Program
>   Files/Orientdb-2.2.34/databases/OSystem
>               DB name="OSystem"
>               at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.create(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:127)
>               at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:438)
>               ... 5

more

Comment: Check if there is no other instance running, which holds lock on `..\log\orient-server.log.0.lck`

Comment: Have you tried to run a "clean" version of orientdb??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to edit your `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern` in `orientdb-server-log-properties` to an absolute path instead of a relative.

e.g. C:\Program Files\Orientdb-2.2.34\log

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on Windows with Server.BAT, then that BAT requires its working directory is set to there. You can edit the `orientdb-server-log-properties` and that's a correct answer.

Alternately, you can just change the working directory to where the `bin` is and start the server from there without a need to change the config file and that's what I opted to do.

I have a small orientStart.ps1 file that I can run from anywhere that look like this.

The environment `ORIENTDB_HOME` is always required.

```
    Push-Location
    $env:ORIENTDB_HOME="C:\orientdb-3.1.1"
    Set-Location $env:ORIENTDB_HOME\bin
    $SERVER ="server.bat"
    cmd /c $SERVER
    Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Start OrientDB's server.bat from within a Windows CLI that has been started with Admin privileges.